# python compare a list to a list in a file,without overwriting the file

Tags: python

i am trying to find away how to check using the python script if there is new vcenter farm

let say i have currently 5 farms

Farm01
Farm02
Farm03
Farm04
Farm05

if new vmware farm let say Farm6 i want  the script to detect it 
so i thought to write the exiting farms to file and compare it to the exiting farm list 
but the file is getting ovewriten ,here is what i did so far

```
f=open('farms_file',"w+")
for farms_items in all_farms_list:
    f.write("%s\n" % farms_items)

f.close()
file = open('farms_file','r')
f_content = file.read()
for i in f_content.split():
    #print i will print all farms in the file
if i not in all_farms_list:
    print(i)
```

but i am not getting any results as the file is overwritten

can you please provide away so the file will not be overriten so i will get 
the new farm

for example farm6

Comment: Write to it after reading it?

Comment: ... and make your life easier using ["with open() as"](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your file is getting overwritten every time is because you are opening it in write mode. To sort this issue just open it in append mode by changing a line :

```
f=open('farms_file',"w+")
```

to

```
f=open('farms_file',"a+")
```

this will protect your file from being overwritten and append the content too.